# the new create form and post "Subject" and "Message"

Tags: php, laravel

When the user(logged-in) posts, the new create form has only "Subject" and "Message" input fields, and when the post is displayed, "Subject","Message","Poster's(user's) name" and "Id".

I think post controller is wrong.
because I can't post even if I press the "Post" button.

UserController.php

```php
    /**
    * バリデーション、登録データの整形など
    */
    public function store(PostRequest $request)
    {
        $subject    = $request->input('subject');
        $message    = $request->input('message');
        $post  = new Post;
        $params = [
            'subject' => $subject,
            'message' => $message,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'name' => Auth::user(),
        ];
        return redirect('/bbs')->with('poststatus', 'Posted !');
    }
```

Post.php

```php
    /**
     * 投稿データを登録する
     */
    public function postSave($params)
    {
        $isSave = $this->fill($params)->save();
        return $isSave;
    }
```

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('is_deleted', 4)->default('0');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); #->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

#### PostRequest.php

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:40',
            'subject' => 'required|max:80',
            'message' => 'required|max:350',
           
        ];
    }
```

#### index.blade.php

```
   @foreach ($posts as $post)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ optional ($post)->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ optional ($post->created_at)->format('Y.m.d') }}</td>
                <td>{{$post->user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ optional ($post)->subject }}</td>
                <td>{!! nl2br(e(Str::limit($post->message, 100))) !!}
                @if ($post->comments->count() >= 1)
                    <p><span class="badge badge-primary">コメント：{{ optional ($post->comments)->count() }}件</span></p>
                @endif
```

Comment: waht is the error?

Comment: there is no error displayed.

Comment: please ``dd($params)`` in your ``Post.php`` inside of your ``postSave`` function and show the result

Answer (score 2):

The most important problem you have is the fact that you don't create a post.

Second, your validation should throw an error because the name is required, but you set the value after validation. Actually, you don't need to validate the name because it will come from your database.

Let's start with the controller:

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
   $request->user_id = Auth::id(),
   $request->name = Auth::user()->name,
   Post::create($request);
   return redirect('/bbs')->with('poststatus', 'Posted !');
}
```

Now, we can work on validation.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'subject' => 'required|max:80',
        'message' => 'required|max:350',
           
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got this error, "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php on line 23"

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(PostRequest $request)
{
  $request->user_id = Auth::id(),
   $request->name = Auth::user()->name,
   Post::create($request);
   return redirect('/bbs')->with('poststatus', 'Posted !');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this error, "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php on line 23"